# Python IndexError: list index out of range - 2d list iteration

Tags: python, list, iteration, turtle-graphics

Trying to iterate through the following 2d list in Python to find an x,y co-ordinate for turtle graphics.

```
data_set_01 = [['A', 1, 0, 'N'], ['A', 2, 1, 'E'], ['A', 3, 2, 'S'], ['A', 4, 3, 'W']]
```

Have the following code:

```
def draw_icons(data_set):
for xpos in data_set: #find x co-ordinates
    if data_set[[xpos][1]] == 0:
        xpos = -450
    elif data_set[[0][1]] == 1:
        xpos = -300
    elif data_set[[xpos][1]] == 2:
        xpos = -150
    elif data_set[[xpos][1]] == 3:
        xpos = 0
    elif data_set[[xpos][1]] == 4:
        xpos = 150
    elif data_set[[xpos][1]] == 5:
        xpos = 300

for ypos in data_set: #find y co-ordinates
    if data_set[[ypos][2]] == 0:
        ypos = -300
    elif data_set[[ypos][2]] == 1:
        ypos = -150
    elif data_set[[ypos][2]] == 2:
        ypos = 0
    elif data_set[[ypos][2]] == 3:
        ypos = 150

goto(xpos,ypos)
pendown()
setheading(90)
commonwealth_logo()
```

Get the following error:

```
if data_set[[xpos][1]] == 0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Better learn to use a debugger. See [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) for instance.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: data_set_01 is not data_set, so your not sharing code and im willing to bet money your not debugging. "Why isnt this code working" questions are useless without enough context and should never be asked without you researching that error and debugging your code first.

Comment: Apologies - new to this.  Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**

Also , seems like `xpos` is actually the complete element in your data_set since you do - `for xpos in data_set:` , if you so can simply do the -

```
xpos[1] #instead of `data_set[[xpos][1]]` .
```

Similarly at all other places.

---

You seem to be indexing your lists wrongly . When you do -

```
data_set[[xpos][1]]
```

You are actually creating a list of single element `xpos` and then accessing its 2nd element (index - 1) from it, it would always error out.

This is not how you index 2D list in Python. You need to access like -

```
list2d[xindex][yindex]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's extract `xpos` & `ypos` together and calculate the position:

```
data_set_01 = [['A', 1, 0, 'N'], ['A', 2, 1, 'E'], ['A', 3, 2, 'S'], ['A', 4, 3, 'W']]

def draw_icons(data_set):
    for _, xpos, ypos, letter in data_set:

        x = (xpos - 3) * 150
        y = (ypos - 2) * 150

        goto(x, y)
        pendown()
        setheading(90)
        write(letter, align='center')  # just for testing

draw_icons(data_set_01)
```